# Enable mat button only on object change

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-toggle-button` which I would like to make clickable only when an object in the `ts` class is changed, otherwise it should stay greyed out

`<mat-button-toggle (click)="updateChanges()"  appearance="fill">Update changes</mat-button-toggle>`

I thought of using the `SimpleChanges` API for this as it tracks status changes on a registered object (ideal for my case).

```
@Input() myObject: MyObject;
public updateButtonClickable: boolean = false;
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.myObject) {
            this.updateButtonClickable = true;
        } else {
            this.updateButtonClickable = false;
        }
    }
```

The first problem is that this approach detects changes at page loading, so my boolean flag variable will be set to true when the page loads, annoying as i would not define this a status change.
Now my second issue is to bind the button status to this variable value, i have been looking at the [material](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api) page but i dont see the way how I could achive this, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could compare if we have `previousValue`. And if `previousValue` is not the same as `currentValue` then it must be a new obj. We use `[disabled]` to "gray out" and make the button not clickable if `updateButtonClickable` boolean is `false`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<p>Complex: {{ complex | json }}</p><br>
  <button [disabled]="!updateButtonClickable">I am button</button>
  <br>
  <br>`,
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() myObject: any;
  public updateButtonClickable: boolean = false;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.myObject) {
      console.log(changes);
      if (
        changes.myObject.previousValue != undefined &&
        changes.myObject.previousValue != changes.myObject.currentValue
      ) {
        console.log('yes now enable');
        this.updateButtonClickable = true;
      } else {
        this.updateButtonClickable = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-on-changes-example-v44p6v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts